# Using Adobe XD Protoype mode, how can I prevent the "go back" mode when using transitions

Tags: mac, adobe-xd

On MacOS, using Adobe XD Protoype mode, I created a transition between two artboards **A** and **B**. The transition on Artboard A has the following parameters :

```
 * Trigger : tap
 * Action : Transition
 * Destination : Artboard B
 * Animation : none
```

Artboard A is set as the home. When launching the prototype, I'm able to get from Artboard A to Artboard B, *`but then, every part of the Artboard B become clickable, and redirect to Artboart B.`*

I don't want the Artboard B to redirect to the previous Artboard. Is that possible ?